# Pack file to MsLZ

Tags: file, compression, packing

How can I pack (compress) file(s) to the type *MsLZ*?

I can't find any packers.

Answer (score 0):

A google search suggests that those are created by *makecab*.

Comment: Really? What is the parameter for MsLZ? I get only MSZip / LZX.

Comment: Otherwise there really isn't much about this format. Why do you need it anyway?

Comment: I saw it from driver files that have the MsLZ format and I added a new file and I want it to the MsLZ.

Answer (score 0):

Use compress.exe from Microsoft. It produces MsLZ compressed files.
Mine has the following prompt then started:

```
Microsoft (R) File Compression Utility  Version 2.00
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1990-1992.
```

(This was taken from InstallShield PackageForTheWeb 2.0 folder, which can be downloaded from https://archive.org/details/pftw20.)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, you can use mscompress found here: https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/mscompress.htm that will compress data in the same LZ77 algorithm